# send email not working Using Sendgrid & mail_form for heroku app. I get NoMethodError in Contacts#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid, mail-form

Hi I just followed tutorial setting up for email contact action from https://youtu.be/QIoORYeBdhs?list=PL23ZvcdS3XPK9Y4DRU-BiJtiY5L_QhUUq

I have following:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
        @contact.request = request
        if @contact.deliver
            flash.now[:error] = nil
        else
            flash.now[:error] = "Cannot send an email."
            render :new
        end
    end
end

class Contact < MailForm::Base
    attribute :name,      :validate => true
    attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i

    attribute :message

    def headers
        {
          :subject => "My Contact Form",
          :to => "testing@gmail.com",
          :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
        }
    end
end
```

And I have views:

```
views/contacts/new.html.erb
<h1> Say Hello </h1>

<div>
    <%=form_for @contact do |f|%>
        <h3>Your are now: <%=current_user.email%> </h3>

        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :name, required: true %>

        <%= f.label :email %><br>
        <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>

        <%= f.label :message %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text %>


        <%=f.submit 'Send message', class: 'button' %>
    <%end%>
</div>

views/contacts/create.html.erb
<h1> email sent </h1>

<div>
    <h3> email Sent! </h3>
</div>
```

I have config/routes.rb

```
  resources :textbook_giveaways
  resources :textbooks
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

  devise_for :users
```

And when I run 'rake routes'

```
contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)                 contacts#create
new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)          contacts#new
```

When I click button 'Send message', I get error:

```
NoMethodError in Contacts#create
undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

    <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var duration = parseInt('<%= msg.length %>');
          duration = (duration >= 100) ? 6000 : 4000;
          noty({
            theme: 'bootstrapTheme',
```

Can you please help with this?

**Update:**
I fixed this problem, please look at the answer below.

Comment: `@contact.request = request` whats request in contact ?

Comment: @7urkm3n Should I fix that thing? I just followed the YouTube video.

Comment: u r assigning there `request` for what ? try just remove it

Comment: @7urkm3n I removed and stil same error.

Comment: i see where is your problem, its in `<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>` that msg is nil thats why u getting this error `undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @7urkm3n I typed message when I sending email. So it can't be nil I think.

Comment: @7urkm3n Can you help with my another question that extends this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672859/how-can-i-grab-or-access-different-model-attribute-when-i-send-email-using-sendg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was wrong. I fixed flash[:success] = "Email sent."

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
        #@contact.request = request
        if @contact.deliver
            flash[:success] = "Email sent."
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Cannot send an email."
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```